# In my WPF project installer, how do I bundle the .NET3.5 installer?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, installation

I developed some WPF projects, but I met a very serious issue. As you know, the .Net 3.5 installation is a pain (huge and relying on internet access). This is a problem on when we ship my product. Is there a way to bundle the redistribution part only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can chain the 3.5 redistributable into your applications installer.  This page on MSDN details all of the work needed to achieve this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Wow I wouldn't do that. It's going to bloat your installer, thus people who have 3.5 already are going to be penalized on the application download.

Just set the installer to require 3.5 as a prerequisite, and if it's missing for some users, they will just download it during the install of your application.

Comment: The option that we went with was to include the full installer on our install media. If .NET 3.5 is installed, the user is not penalized. If it isn't installed, our bootstrap app will let the user know and launch the .NET installer after the user clicks a button to do so. (This gives the user the opportunity to cancel and launch it manually if he wants.) By including the full .NET installer, the user doesn't need internet access to install .NET (and our product suite).